# 28 hour day during creation

Tags: creation

As we can see in the article below, the original 6 days of creation were 28 hours long. Can anyone provide any more supporting info on this item? Maybe someone here has info from hebrew seforim that are not in english online.

Google searches are not helping.

***Rabbi Eliyahu of Izmir in his commentary to Chumash (Parashas Ki Sisa) quotes a Midrash that states that initially, G-d created not seven 24-hour days, but six 28-hours days.***

Source: https://www.kosher.com/article/having-shabbat-on-our-minds-throughout-the-week-409

Comment: Have you looked through Bereshit Rabbah on Setaria? They published a complete English translation earlier this year

Comment: You worded the first sentence wrong. We don't see that the days were 28 hours, that would be absolutely meaningless because the division into hours is artificial. We only see that the article quotes Rabbi Eliyahoo who quotes a Midrash.

Comment: How about סוף מעשה במחשבה תחילה? Does the rabbi say that God didn't intend to have Shabbos until Time objected?

Comment: This is the OP. The request was for the community to kindly 'provide any more supporting info on this item'. Ty